# Running a python script in background with raw_input command

Tags: python, background, raw-input

I have a python script that has a raw input command, but I would like to run it in the background after the user inputs the raw_input part. The problem I have is if I try running the script in the background using &, the raw input pops up as a linux command and the python script doesn't recognize it.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`fork`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fork) to create a child process and then exit the parent.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys
import time

_ = raw_input('Enter the the secret code: ')
if os.fork(): # returns 0 in the child, pid of the child in the parent
    sys.exit()

time.sleep(2)
print('All good things must come to an end')
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to run the script in the foreground, but then call `os.fork()` after the user has input the value.